# Navigation bar jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm a student learning some really basic HTML coding and I decided to use a simple JavaScript navigation bar so that the drop down menu has some animation speed.

The navigation bar was previously working but after adding my image slider it stopped working.

Thanks for the help!

```js
// JavaScript NavBar
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#navbar ul li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
    
    $('#navbar ul li').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#navbar ul', this).stop().slideDown(500);
      });
    $('#navbar ul li').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#navbar ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
      });
    });
```

```css
* {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    }
    
    body{
     background:url(../images/subtle_white_mini_waves.png) repeat;
     font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
     color: white;
    }
    
    #navbar{
     margin-left:-400px;
     position:absolute;
     left:50%;
    }
    
    #navbar a{
     text-decoration:none;
    }
     
    .button{
     background:url(../images/navbarbutton.png);
     margin-top: 66px;
     width: 170px;
    }
    
    .button:hover{
     background:#e6e6e6;
    }
    
    .button a{
     padding: 34px 0px;
    }
    
    #navbar ul{
     text-align:center;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li{
     float: left;
     display: inline;
     font-size:16px;
     height:89px;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li:hover{
     background:#E6E6E6;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li a{
     display:block;
     color: #444;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li ul{
     position:absolute;
     width: 170px;
     background:#fff;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li ul li{
     width: 170px;
     
    }
    
    #navbar ul li ul li a{
     display:block;
     padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
     color: #444;
     font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li ul li:hover a{
     background:#f7f7f7;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li ul.fallback{
     display:none;
    }
    
    #navbar ul li:hover ul.fallback{
     display:block;
    }
    
    .shadows{
     position:absolute;
     z-index:10;
    }
    
    #shadowtopleft{
     margin-left:4.6875%;
     margin-right:140px;
     float:left;
    }
    
    #shadowtopright{
     float:left;
    }
    
    #shadowbottomleft{
     margin-top: 83px;
     margin-left:4.6875%;
     margin-right:140px;
     float:left;
    }
    
    #shadowbottomright{
     margin-top: 83px;
     float:left;
    }
    
    .banner {
     z-index:-1;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .banner ui{
     list-style:none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .banner ul li {
     display:block;
        float:left;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
     min-height:500px;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Beyond - Home</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/NavBar.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/unslider.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <!--NavBar start-->
    <div id="navbar">
     <ul>
         <li class="button"><a href="#">Programmes</a>
             <ul class="fallback">
                 <li><a href="#">Problem De-esclation</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Family Strengthening</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Community Integration</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Support Programmes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#">How You Can Help</a>
             <ul class="fallback">
                 <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Sponsor</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Partner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Join The Staff</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
             <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="140" height="225" alt="Beyond - Logo"></a>
          </div>
            </li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#">About Beyond</a>
             <ul class="fallback">
                 <li><a href="#">Our board</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News and Views</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
             <ul class="fallback">
                 <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--NavBar end-->
    <!--Shadows start-->
    <div class="shadows">
     <div id="shadowtopleft">
     <img src="images/shadowtopleft.png" width="520" height="66">
     </div>
     <div id="shadowtopright">
     <img src="images/shadowtopright.png" width="520" height="66">
     </div>
     <div id="shadowbottomleft">
     <img src="images/shadowbottomleft.png" width="520" height="13">
     </div>
     <div id="shadowbottomright">
     <img src="images/shadowbottomright.png" width="520" height="13">
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--Shadows end-->
    <!--Unslider start-->
    <div class="banner">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://techkaps.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/1280x720_hd_wallpaper_123_zixpkcom.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="http://techkaps.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/1280x720_hd_wallpaper_123_zixpkcom.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="http://techkaps.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/1280x720_hd_wallpaper_123_zixpkcom.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.banner').unslider({
     speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
     delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
     complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
     keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
     dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
     fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
      });
     });
    </script>
    <!--Unslider end-->
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are a student, you might have not of heard of the [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) style property. The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element, especially if you are using `position: absolute;` a lot.

So your menu menu, `#navbar`, is there. It's just hidden under other elements, so you might want to add the z-index style to your code, like this:

```
#navbar {
   margin-left: -400px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 100;
}
```

I also thought that I'd mention that in your CSS code, you made a tiny error:

```
.banner ui{
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Should be:

```
.banner ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I combined my answer and put it inside if the code snippet below.

```js
// JavaScript NavBar
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navbar ul li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');

  $('#navbar ul li').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#navbar ul', this).stop().slideDown(500);
  });
  $('#navbar ul li').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#navbar ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: url(../images/subtle_white_mini_waves.png) repeat;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
#navbar {
  margin-left: -400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
}
#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button {
  background: url(../images/navbarbutton.png);
  margin-top: 66px;
  width: 170px;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
.button a {
  padding: 34px 0px;
}
#navbar ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 89px;
}
#navbar ul li:hover {
  background: #E6E6E6;
}
#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #444;
}
#navbar ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  background: #fff;
}
#navbar ul li ul li {
  width: 170px;
}
#navbar ul li ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#navbar ul li ul li:hover a {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
#navbar ul li ul.fallback {
  display: none;
}
#navbar ul li:hover ul.fallback {
  display: block;
}
.shadows {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
#shadowtopleft {
  margin-left: 4.6875%;
  margin-right: 140px;
  float: left;
}
#shadowtopright {
  float: left;
}
#shadowbottomleft {
  margin-top: 83px;
  margin-left: 4.6875%;
  margin-right: 140px;
  float: left;
}
#shadowbottomright {
  margin-top: 83px;
  float: left;
}
.banner {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.banner ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.banner ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Beyond - Home</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/NavBar.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/unslider.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--NavBar start-->
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="button"><a href="#">Programmes</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
          <li><a href="#">Problem De-esclation</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Family Strengthening</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Community Integration</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Support Programmes</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="button"><a href="#">How You Can Help</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsor</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Partner</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Join The Staff</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="logo">
          <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/logo.png" width="140" height="225" alt="Beyond - Logo">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="button"><a href="#">About Beyond</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
          <li><a href="#">Our board</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">News and Views</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="button"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
          <li><a href="#">Facilities</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Feedback</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--NavBar end-->
  <!--Shadows start-->
  <div class="shadows">
    <div id="shadowtopleft">
      <img src="images/shadowtopleft.png" width="520" height="66">
    </div>
    <div id="shadowtopright">
      <img src="images/shadowtopright.png" width="520" height="66">
    </div>
    <div id="shadowbottomleft">
      <img src="images/shadowbottomleft.png" width="520" height="13">
    </div>
    <div id="shadowbottomright">
      <img src="images/shadowbottomright.png" width="520" height="13">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Shadows end-->
  <!--Unslider start-->
  <div class="banner">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://techkaps.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/1280x720_hd_wallpaper_123_zixpkcom.jpg">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://techkaps.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/1280x720_hd_wallpaper_123_zixpkcom.jpg">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://techkaps.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/1280x720_hd_wallpaper_123_zixpkcom.jpg">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.banner').unslider({
        speed: 500, //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
        delay: 3000, //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
        complete: function() {}, //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
        keys: true, //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
        dots: true, //  Display dot navigation
        fluid: false //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!--Unslider end-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice spot, King Shimkus :)

Comment: I've changed it but it isn't the problem. Thanks for the spot though!

Comment: @CyborgCommunist, I have made changes to your code. I spent a while looking at the code and trying to find an answer. And I finally got it. Sorry, I couldn't find it sooner.